# Why would you set a bounty on a question that you answered already?

Tags: discussion, bounties

This is a case that puzzles me, being newly active on stack exchange (although I've been using for years as a visitor). The specific question is: [Electronics System Standards Compliance: Certification, Testing & Verification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231159/electronics-system-standards-compliance-certification-testing-verification)

The person that made the already accepted answer (which is great, by the way) has set a bounty on the question afterwards.

Why would you do that? The bounty will go to himself, right? Is it to challenge other potential answers? I think there is little chance someone will come with a greater answer. Is it just to encourage more voting on his own answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would you do that ?

They might think their answer is not complete or has some other issues. Perhaps they want to see how others approach the problem.

> The bounty will go to himself, right ?

Nope. That's not how bounties work. The person who offered the bounty can select who to award it to (not themselves), if they don't and new answers come in and get voted up, one of them will automatically get (half) the bounty value.

> Is it just to encourage more voting on his own answer ?

It is possible. But it is a strange way to "game" the system - by taking away rep in order to gain some.

Comment: Ok, so all this confirms it is rather unusual.

Comment: Not common, but no unheard of.

Answer (score 9):

No, the bounty won't go to himself. The bounty will never return to its raiser. In the bounty reason, the bounty raiser wrote:

> I would like to see more answers from a wider variety of people on this subject

So clearly that user isn't satisfied with the answers given, or just wants more varieties of them. That is a perfect reason to start a bounty. Some raise a bounty to get an (first) answer, some do it to award to an excellent answer. All that is perfectly fine.

A bounty is not the best way to attract votes to your question. He will need 10 votes just to break even on the bounty investment, which is not likely to happen with 14 votes on it now. And even then it would be a gamble.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't actually read the bounty reason. I supposed that was some generic message and skipped it. So I have my answer.

Comment: However, the answer from the guy that set the bounty got 14 votes. It's the question that has 6 votes only. And it's 10 votes to break even, right ? I think you mixed it up: the guy that set the bounty is not the asker, it's the one that made the accepted answer. But nevermind, you raised the point.

Comment: Oh, yes. Missed that. That would make ten indeed. Still not very likely to gain that much for just a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Ironically (as I am the OP), a few months after this event, I also decided to propose a bounty on a question after having answered it.

Basically, I made an answer that was satisfying enough for the OP, but I realized afterwards that it didn't address all concerns accurately enough. Since my knowledge wasn't sufficient to explain the missing bits, and for the sake of completeness, I offered a bounty to encourage people explaining the missing points (which turned out a bit disappointing because the subsequent answers weren't more complete, but it's part of the game).

So there are actually multiple reasons for this case.